# Unable to suppress /health in Spring boot actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

On my application.properties i have endpoints.enabled=false and also endpoints.health.enabled=false but still the /health endpoint is not getting suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the first level of the properties.
The properties should be configured like this, to disable all endpoints

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default= false
```

if you only want to disable the health endpoint than use this property:

```
    management.endpoint.health.enabled=false
```

Comment: hi, I dont have spring security in my project at all. i am not able to find this property management.endpoints.enabled-by-default at all

Comment: Can you share more information about your environment, e.g. spring boot version, the content of your application.properties

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues here could be the version of Sprint Boot being used. 1.5.x has different properties to 2.0.x.

**Spring Boot 2.0.x**

management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false

management.endpoint.health.enabled=false

management.endpoint.info.enabled=true

**Spring Boot 1.5.x**

endpoints.enabled=false

endpoint.health.enabled=false

endpoint.info.enabled=true

Please also note that when enabling endpoints you use plural ("endpoints") but when enabling a specific endpoint you use a singlton ("endpoint").